# How to find unique pairs of a quad tree?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, data-structures, quadtree

I am using a quad tree data structure to find nearby objects on a 2D plane. I have already implemented a working quad tree which returns an array for each object including all of it's neighbours. The problem is, I need each unique pair of objects from this group of lists.

Let's say I have the following points [a, b, c, d] in an array. And that:

**a** is near **b**,

**b** is near **c**,

**c** is near **d**,

Therefore,

**a** is NOT near **c** or **d**,

**b** is NOT near **d**,

**c** is NOT near **a**,

**d** is NOT near **a** or **b**,

Therefore by iterating over each object and asking for it's neighbours, I will get the following array, where each element is an array of its own where the first element is the object in question and each other element are it's neighbours:

```
[
  [a, b],       // a is only near b
  [b, a, c],    // So b is near c and also a
  [c, b, d],    // So c is near b and also d
  [d, c]        // d is only near c
]
```

I want an array containing only the unique pairs of neighbouring objects (E.g. having both [a, b] and [b, a] is unacceptable) and so in this case the solution would be:

```
[
  [a, b],
  [b, c],
  [c, d]
]
```

How can I achieve this result?

Also it would be greatly appreciated if the code was as optimised as possible. Thank you so much!

Comment: Show a minimal working example in which you need help.

Comment: @DominiqueFortin I am not entirely sure what you mean. I cannot really show a codepen as the quadtree itself is too complicated to implement. I am just asking for a function to filter an array from [[a,b],[b,a,c],[c,b,d],[d,c]] to [[a,b],[b,c],[c,d]].

Comment: You should come to Stackoverflow for help on something concrete you've made, not ask for somebody to code something for you.

Comment: @DominiqueFortin I'm sure the solution to my problem is actually a pretty simple Array.filter function or something but I can't work out how to do it. I have coded this quad tree and the objects, but its all part of a much larger program that won't fit onto a codepen example, even if you don't want to give me any code, you could at least point me in a direction. So it is concrete, I'm just posting a question like everyone else does. I'll see if I can make a small code example...

Comment: No it is not simple. Maybe using reduce but I'm not sure.

Comment: @DominiqueFortin I solved the problem, it was in fact not overly complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking more around those lines

```js
let unsortedArray = [
  ['a', 'b'],
  ['b', 'a', 'c'],
  ['c', 'b', 'd'],
  ['d', 'c']
];

function solver(arr) {
  let marked = {};
  let result = [];
  
  arr.forEach((arcs) => {
    let first;
    arcs.forEach((vertex, i) =>{
      if (i === 0 ) {
        first = vertex;
      } else {
        let forward = first+vertex, backward = vertex+first;

        if (!marked.hasOwnProperty(forward) && !marked.hasOwnProperty(backward)) {
          result.push([first, vertex]);
        }
        marked[forward] = 0;
        marked[backward] = 0;
      }
    });
  });
  
  return result;
}

console.log(solver(unsortedArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the sorting but it is quite computationally expensive, if anyone knows how to shorten this code it would be greatly appreciated!

```js
let unsortedArray = [
  ['a', 'b'],
  ['b', 'a', 'c'],
  ['c', 'b', 'd'],
  ['d', 'c']
];

function solver(arr) {
  // Detach first elements
  let groups = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let body = arr[i].shift();
    groups[i] = {body, others: arr[i]};
  }
  // Get all pairs
  let pairs = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < groups[i].others.length; j++) {
      let pair = [groups[i].body, groups[i].others[j]];
      pairs.push(pair);
    }
  }
  // Filter non unique pairs
  for (let i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < pairs.length; j++) {
      if (pairs[i] == pairs[j] || (pairs[i][0] == pairs[j][1] && pairs[i][1] == pairs[j][0])) {
        pairs.splice(j, 1);
      }
    }
  }
  return pairs;
}

let sortedArray = solver(unsortedArray);
console.log(sortedArray);
```